# function rendering on blank page

Tags: php, cakephp

I've a hyper-link when we're clicking on hyper-link it got a parameter of year but it can't load data based on year and shows a blank page with continuously loading...

hyper-link :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('click me', array('controller'=>'dashboards', 'action'=>'myfunction', $year)); ?>
```

myfunction on usercontroller :

```
public function getsessionlist($year) {
    $session = $this->find('all');
}
```

Right now i'm getting all data without any condition...
But it redirect on blank page

Comment: Create a view for "getsessionlist" function

Comment: i've created a view for getsessionlist() already

Comment: how about the layout?

Comment: I'm using my default layout front.ctp which is calling everywhere..

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled in your core.php (Configure::write('debug', 2);)  in order to display the right message error instead of a blank page ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the redirection to the blank page is occuring due to the wrong mention of the controller/method name.

you can debug the problem by three methods:-

1.you can hard code the link and check if it redirects to the right page.
  ex:

```
<a href='controllername/methodname?queries-if-you-have-any'>link name</a>
```

If this works out fine, then check the parameters you have passed in the link method.

2.You can debug the link from the browser console and see what is coming up in the "href" section of the link tag.

3.you can manually type the link in the url and see if the blank page is still coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$this->find('all')` from the controller does not work unless you have a method called "find" implemented in the controller. This method is called on a model so edit the line to `$this->User->find('all')` in your case.